# python3 regex findall working on MULTILINE

Tags: python-re

I have difficulty to write a regex in python to do *findall()*, and find out all the matched texts, somehow, it didn't work in the way I want. Can someone help me to figure out how to write the correct regex in this case?
Also, why re.compile(r'^all:.*?\n$', re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE) get 2 matches?

**try_findall.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import re

# this returns only 2 matches, expect to return 3 matches
allRe = re.compile(r'^all:.*?\n$', re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE)

# this returns 3 matches, but only matchs till create_links\n, it is expected to match all the texts before next all target
allRe1 = re.compile(r'^all:.*?$\n', re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE)

with open('targets.inc', 'r') as f:
    line = f.read()
    # print(line)

    all_recipes = allRe.findall(line)
    # all_recipes = allRe1.findall(line)    
    print(len(all_recipes))
    
    for recipe in all_recipes:
        print(recipe)
        print('*'*30 + '\n')
```

**target.inc**

```
ifeq ($(TARG),MULTI_CMD)
all: create_links
    cd ../ 
export EXTRA_OVERRIDES += MULTI_CMD_SRC=1 FRAME_NUM=21 START_FRAME_NUM=100
else ifeq ($(TARG),MULTI_CMD_UPDATE_PPS)
all: create_links
    cd frame_files;\
export EXTRA_OVERRIDES += MULTI_CMD_SRC=2 FRAME_NUM=18 START_FRAME_NUM=3

else ifeq ($(TARG),MULTI_CMD_MULTI_SLICE_CABAC)
all: create_links
    cd frame_files;\
export EXTRA_OVERRIDES += MULTI_CMD_SRC=6 FRAME_NUM=3 SLICE_NUM=4 START_FRAME_NUM=0
endif
```